# How to query issuetype and priority?

Tags: jira, jql

I have a simple filter [ project = 'XXX' and issuetype in (Bug, Story) ] that I use for the Two Dimensional Filter Statistics gadget. It shows perfectly the number of Bugs and Stories per Sprint.

But, I would like to go down a bit by splitting the number of Bugs by priority, so it'll show the number of High Priority bugs, Low Priority bugs, and Stories per Sprint.

Anyone knows what is the query ?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can only get that kind of granular detail if you go per sprint.

Depending on how many Sprints you have (say 3) you may be able to make 3 *Two Dimensional Gadgets* and view all of them on your *Dashboard* (See picture for an example of one of the 3 in this case).

The query would then be:

```
project = 'XXX' and issuetype in (Bug, Story) and Sprint = 'YYY'
```

Pic:
[Two Dimensional Filter Statistics (IssueType vs Priority) per Sprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmWNV.png)